# not able to convert string to date

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, nsdate, xcode10.1

I have an string say , "24:00". I need to convert to date.I tried all the ways.But always getting nil.

here is my code :

```
let timeformat = DateFormatter()
timeformat.dateFormat = "K:mm"
timeformat.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
guard let endtime = dateFormatter.date(from: selCloseTime!) else {
                fatalError("ERROR: Date conversion failed due to mismatched format.")
            }
```

> error: Fatal error: ERROR: Date conversion failed due to mismatched
>   format.

i tried changing  format to :

```
HH:mm
H:mm
KK:mm (small & caps  -> k)
K:mm (small & caps - > k)
```

but always getting nil. My string can be anything like :

```
"24.00", "01:00", "20:00" , "03:00"
```

Any help on that .

Thanks in advance ~

Comment: try timeformat.date(from: selCloseTime!) ?

Comment: @KingofBliss same nil only ia m getting

Comment: Two different variables `timeformat ` and `dateFormatter ` which one are you using to format the date object?

Comment: @macrodues to found an actual date you need to pass time with date, month and year by this data you only convert it to time format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `timeformat.dateFormat = "K:mm"` to `timeformat.dateFormat = "kk:mm"` and see this output.

```
let selCloseTime = "20:00"
let timeformat = DateFormatter()
timeformat.dateFormat = "kk:mm"
timeformat.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
guard let endtime = timeformat.date(from: selCloseTime) else {
    fatalError("ERROR: Date conversion failed due to mismatched format.")
}
print(endtime)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Time format 24 hours to 12 hours**

```
let dateAsString = "13:15"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"

let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateAsString)
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "h:mm a"
let Date12 = dateFormatter.string(from: date!)
print("12 hour formatted Date:",Date12) // 1:15 PM
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, but please know that you will not have the todays date since you've only set the hour/minute, it doesn't know what year, month or day you want.

```
let dateString = "20:32"
let df = DateFormatter()
df.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
let d = df.date(from: dateString) // "Jan 1, 2000 at 8:32 PM"
```

Comment: it's Return **2000-01-01 15:02:00 +0000** wrong time